# Magento 1 location of search bar code

Tags: magento-1.7, search, catalogsearch

I am trying to move my search bar bar into the white bar so that I can delete the tan bar:

[image]

But I don't know where to look to find the code for the search bar either in the admin panel or in code.

Answer (score 1):

if you looking for some piece of code, and need to know which file exactly have it, you can quickly `grep` it:

```
grep '<form class="form minisearch" id="search_mini_form"' -rl app
```

it will find the file:

```
app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Search/templates/form.mini.phtml
```

but for a more complex approach you also need to fix (*override*) `css` too, because moving the code is not so easy without fixing `css` as well. design will fall apart.

also you need to override original template file with your custom, or use child theme path.

Comment: This is super helpful, I will try this and let you know

Comment: is infortis the name of your theme?

Comment: this is sample grep from Magento 2 Infortis theme, but grep works for everything

Comment: what does -rl mean?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html     `grep options`

Answer (score 0):

In code. It's going to be template and possibly XML change.

I recommend using template hints to work out what is doing what.

> Login to the magento back-end.
>
> Go to System > Configuration.
>
> Go to Developer section on the bottom left under ADVANCED.
>
> Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.
>
> Open Debug and set “Template Path Hints” = Yes
>
> Remember to clear your cache ( System > Cache Management)

I recommend doing this on a dev site if you can.

That's as much as I can tell you at this stage. Hope you find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is what I wanted to do but I inherited the site so I don't have a dev site yet.